# What is the purpose of the STL allocator copy constructor requirement

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, stl

STL places some restrictions on allocators which includes the following:
>

> 1. *a1 == a2* returns true only if the storage allocated by the allocator a1 can be deallocated through a2. Establishes reflexive, symmetric, and transitive relationship. Does not throw exceptions.
> 2. *A a(b)* Constructs a such that B(a)==b and A(b)==a. Does not throw exceptions. (Note: this implies that all allocators related by rebind maintain each other's resources, such as memory pools)
>
> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator

At first I mistakenly interpreted requirement 2 as: "*A a(b)* Constructs a such that a==b." Which I believe may be a common mistake but considering the correct interpretation of 2, in what use cases would it be actually be useful? I imagine that most of the time the copy constructor body will be empty. Could it for example be used for copying a file pointer to be used for the allocations?

Comment: I believe the second requirement is to allow an allocator to `rebind` to a type different from the one it was instantiated with. For instance, a `list<int, allocator<int>>` will need to allocate some `NodeType<int>` instead of `int`s, and that clause ensures that `allocator<int>` behaves the same as `allocator<NodeType<int>>` would.

Comment: But isn't the typedef sufficient for rebinding?

Comment: @JansenduPlessis The typedef is enough for stateless allocators. You need the converting constructors to pass along the state (think e.g. pool allocators that pass the underlying storage). IOW: it's for when the allocator isn't default constructible (or when default construction yields a different result from copy)

Answer (score 0):

As the comment points out, allocators can be rebound to different types.

Most often¹, allocator instances for different types have (implicit) conversions, so you can pass `Alloc<void>` where `Alloc<int>` is expected and vice versa.

So, when you do

```
MyAlloc<int> ia;
MyAlloc<double> da;

bool equivalent = (ia == da);
```

What you actually end up doing is

```
bool equivalent = operator==(ia, da);
```

which would implicitly convert `da` to `MyAlloc<int>`, unless a heterogeneous overload of `operator==` exists.

The requirement is specified requires that the implementation *explicitly* converts the rhs allocator to the same allocator type. This

- avoids accidentally hitting heterogeneous overloads of `operator==` and
- has the benefit of still working even if the conversion constructor is marked `explicit`.

```
bool equivalent = operator==(ia, MyAlloc<int>(da)); // or:
bool equivalent = operator==(da, MyAlloc<double>(ia)); // or:
```

At the same time this allows allocators of different types to still compare *non-equivalent*.

¹ Need to check whether it is specified as a requirement